# Best way to get consistent timings for code in WSL

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, timing

I am trying to time code I have written and am having trouble getting consistent timings. I am running the code in WSL. There is no randomness in my code.

What is the best way to set up my laptop to get more consistent timings? Or is WSL just not a good environment for consistent timings?

Answer (score 1):

WSL uses resources that are made available by the host in order
to run the programs. It doesn't itself consume much resources
and is as deterministic as any operating-system environment.

If you're getting inconsistent timings, check what's running on
the host. Check also if your program has any code that might
entail waiting for a resource (for example internet) that
has an inconsistent availability or waiting time.

Comment: Is it worth rebooting into safe mode and turning off wifi/bluetooth?

Comment: This will reduce resources usage, but only trying will tell if it makes a difference.